# How to delete excess non empty columns after pasting the new data into the spreadsheet using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I don't have any code to provide sample here.

Let me explain my issue here, I want to delete columns from old spreadsheet which is already having 'n' number of columns after copy and pasting the new data which is having not more than the 'n' number of columns in new spreadsheet.

Also, if the number of columns in new spreadsheet are more than the number of columns in old spreadsheet. The columns must do not delete.

Can anyone help me with the vba code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow, lastCol As Integer

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Selecting data from Sheet1
    ws1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Pasting data to Sheet2
    ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Deleting columns, keeping only the first 3 columns
    ws1.Cells(1, 4).Resize(lastRow, lastCol).EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out here, much appreciated.

Actually, what i'm a looking here is, I have two spreadsheets, which is 1 Old one and the other one is New one.

Old one is having 7 columns and New one is having 3 columns. First, I want to Copy and Paste as values of all columns/ cells from New one to Old one. So, after doing that, there will be 7 columns in Old one. But, I wanted that the Old spreadsheet should have only 3 columns not 7. I want to delete those excess columns in Old spreadsheet.

Here, the number of columns in New spreadsheet may varies from time to time.

Comment: I updated my answer, based on it you should be able to do it.
I am not sure if in the old sheet you can just override the data or not.
If yes, just delete everything from the old before pasting the new data. You can do it like this:

`ws2.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol).EntireColumn.Delete`